# How to convert PDF in HTML?

Tags: html, pdf

I know that some similar questions has been asked here, but I saw all of them and no one still satisfy me.

Well, I tried xpdf and pdftohtml both are great, but old and the new version of PDFs seems won't work.

My problem is to find a way that allow me convert any PDF or Doc to HTML and that keep the style and structure. If somebody has something, even paid its perfect.

Comment: Cant remember if this has support to save as pdf but i think it should have. http://www.techsmith.com/snagit/ What I'm sure about is that it lets you take screenshots of entire websites and save them in various image formats. As far as preserving text as text goes.. I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: @Lollero, it's not really what I'm looking for, or I misunderstood something.

Comment: I can see that.._now_. I'm sorry about my failure to properly read ( in general ) I have no idea how well those two preserve stuff but you could use save for web in photoshop.. in which you can add links and such with slice tool and save it as html document.. That would preserve the look 100% but it would basically be just one image.. i wouldnt recommend that if you want your output to be big in size. Plus if you have multiple pages.. the manual processing of the pdf document is not very fast.

Comment: @yms interesting tool, do you have any working example online, better if I can try my own PDF ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I tried some libraries, exclusively for Linux, but here is my intermediate conclusion.

[PDFtoHTML](http://pdftohtml.sourceforge.net/) is too old and doesn't take in consideration all new PDF Specifications, for example PDF 1.7 (mainly because it use xpdf 2.02, while xpdf is already in his 3 version)

Instead of PDFTOHTML I found [Poppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/) that continues the PDFtoHTML development plus some new utils very useful. Actually, in Open Source Poppler was the one who rendered better my complex PDF. [Here](http://www.ren21.net/Portals/97/documents/GSR/GSR2011_Master18.pdf) one almost equal I've to use.

Finally, here is it what I'm gonna use. ImageMagick + Poppler. I will convert my PDF to images and use the XML output from Poppler of PDFtoHTML to add a new layer on my image.

Comment: Actually, I have checked, and PDFtoHTML is based nowadays on xpdf 3:
pdftohtml version 0.36 http://pdftohtml.sourceforge.net/, based on Xpdf version 3.00
    Copyright 1999-2003 Gueorgui Ovtcharov and Rainer Dorsch
Copyright 1996-2004 Glyph & Cog, LLC

Answer (score 1):

Like you i was on the search for an automatic conversion tool from PDF to HTML or even better XHTML. Well, it was only two sides, but after all http://www.pdfonline.com (Online PDF To HTML) did the best job for me. It even is able to filter and correctly display tables and paragraphes, not only phrases!

Still it was not enough for my job, so i generated a template file manually.